# How to enable CORS in jBoss

Tags: jquery, html, web-services, soap, jboss

I am developing an HTML5 application that has to obtain some values from legacy web-services (Jax-Ws) so I use [jQuery.soap](https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap) to query these web services to obtain responses. I have tried the correctness of my requests with SOAP UI, and they work properly.

From my HTML5 client I cannot receive SOAP responses from the server, because in the response there is not the *Allow-Control-Allow-Origin* header set to *. So, the origin of the request is recognized as not allowed, and the response of the server is an error response.

The message of the error, debugging my HTML5 project with Firebug + Firefox, is:

*Locked cross- origin request: the criterion at the origin does not allow the reading of the remote resource. You can solve the problem by moving the resource to the same domain or activating CORS.*

How can I enable CORS in jBoss?

Comment: You need to use a servlet filter like this one: http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to deal with your legacy web-services to fix the issue. As mccannf said above you need to add CORS filter in web.xml.

You can use a solution from thetransactioncompany:

web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

If you use apache Tomcat you can use built-in CorsFilter:

web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.42</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you this solves the hassle to create the filter and test it. Works flawlessly.

Comment: Got this: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/thetransactioncompany/cors/CORSFilter : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 indicating the JBoss program I am using is a  program compiled with a lower version of jdk (JRE 6 1.6) and not able to change this. So, couldn't use this.

Answer (score 2):

you can modify the standalone.xml file, if you are working locally.

modify your filters part of your xml as in the flollowing answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39215400/10623693

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue, disabling the WAPDL (Web Application Description Language) into the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
...
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
...
</servlet>
```