# Wildfly - Allowing Cross-Origin Requests

Tags: java, jboss, server, cross-domain, wildfly

I'm trying to make Wildfly allow Cross-Origin requests, in order to be able to send requests to localhost using local JavaScript code.

Here's a request I'm making via JavaScript:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  

request.open("GET", requestUrl);  
request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");  
request.send();
```

An error is thrown in the dev console when testing in Chrome.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/.... Request header
>   field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

The request fails on Firefox as well, although no error is thrown in this case.

I modified my standalone.xml and restarted Wildfly according to this answer, to no avail:

[CORS: AngularJS + Resteasy 3 + Wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337780/cors-angularjs-resteasy-3-wildfly)

I even tried creating a filter class according to this answer, it didn't help as well:

[How to enable Cross domain requests on JAX-RS web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450494/how-to-enable-cross-domain-requests-on-jax-rs-web-services)

I didn't change any configurations to include this class however, in case such a thing is required for it to work.

Comment: You are setting wrong header in the `XMLHttpRequest` object, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272611/make-cors-ajax-requests-using-xmlhttprequest

Comment: You are right. I don't even need to set headers in JS, as soon as I removed that irrelevant header everything worked properly. Thank you