# Cross origin resource sharing in jboss

Tags: jboss

I have a web service in ejb project. How to add a filtre cors (cross origin resource sharing) in JBoss server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable CORS in jBoss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610657/how-to-enable-cors-in-jboss)